# C# How do I shorten this long over loaded do while statement

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have made a tic tac toe game and I am producing another version with less code. Anyway... here is my code... I've taken some of the code in between the do while statement but yeah...

```
    var rc = new Random();
    do
    {
        storeRI = rc.Next(1, 9);

        if (storeRI == 1 & button1.Text == "")
        {
            button1.Text = "O";
            Turn = 1;
            TestWin();
            break;
        }
        else if (storeRI == 2 & button2.Text == "")
        {
            button2.Text = "O";
            Turn = 1;
            TestWin();
            break;
        }


    } while (Turn == 2 & button1.Text == "" | button2.Text == "" | button3.Text == "" | button3.Text == "" | button4.Text == "" | button5.Text == "" | button6.Text == "" | button7.Text == "" | button8.Text == "" | button9.Text == "");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's a draw");
}
```

I mainly want to focus on this block of code... to shorten down... :)

```
 } while (Turn == 2 & button1.Text == "" | button2.Text == "" | button3.Text == "" | button3.Text == "" | button4.Text == "" | button5.Text == "" | button6.Text == "" | button7.Text == "" | button8.Text == "" | button9.Text == "");
```

Comment: Side note: Using bitwise and/or operators on boolean values is not exactly usual style... Consider `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov with booleans `|` and `&` are not "bit-wise" operators.  They are non-short circuiting versions of `||` and `&&`.  Doesn't make a difference in this case but it's an important distinction.

Comment: That's mainly the problem with winforms: the fact that it actually sucks. If you did this in WPF and MVVM, each of your buttons would be a data item in a ViewModel and you could just compare these data items with each other and so on.

Comment: @HighCore it is easy enough to iterate through the Controls collection of the winform.

Comment: @DStanley, good point about [| operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.100).aspx) not bit-wise for bool. My concern is mainly that using non-standard code implies some special reason to do so, which is probably not the case in the sample. (and good +1 answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I figured that was your intent - just being pedantic :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey winforms actually encourages developers to do pathetic things such as mashing all together the program logic and the UI. whereas WPF does not. All XAML-based technologies quickly encourage modern programming concepts such as MVVM by their very nature. The visual tree is a complex thing, often difficult to manipulate in "traditional" ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a List of buttons from your individual buttons and then change it to

```
while(Turn==2 && buttons.Any(b => b.Text == ""))
```

In general with 9 buttons they should probably be in an array or list for simpler access:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] {button1, button2, button3, ... } ;
```

then you can access it as `buttons[0]` instead of `button1`, etc.

I would do this in your Form initializer rather than having a function that does this on-demand.

Comment: I have a collection of buttons that I refer to many times, I've put this in a private method called addbuttons(); maybe I could refer to this, if so how? I hope it's not too much to ask =)

Comment: By "collection" I mean an array or list, not `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, etc.  I'll update my answer.